Unable to withdraw money
I had a bot from which I regularly withdrew money through the contract after May 27, the withdrawal contract stopped working, more precisely, when I tried to call the contract, an error occurred why can this happen
I'm a bot owner, the money is on solana's contract, I can't withdraw money from the contract because when I try to do something, I get the error "Contract error on solana blockchain"
But i was able to withdraw money from the contract until may 27-30
Before solana’s update

You need to provide more information about the contract, or even the transaction signature where the said claim is failing.
